# Saving XML node back in my table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I have a query where i use `XML.modify` in sql to insert a new node into my xml doc

However i print this XML and i see my XML doc updated, but nothing saves in my database

Do i need an update script here for the changes to take effect? (The column in the database is of type text but i cast it into an XML

Comment: Yes, you need UPDATE or INSERT may be. `XML.modify` just makes some computations on the XML value the same way  as for example arithmetic operator `+` does.  But to store newly computed value in the table you must instruct DBMS explicitly to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the column in place like this:

```
create table #t( id int, doc xml)
insert into #t(id,doc) values (1,'<a><b/></a>')

update #t set doc.modify( 'delete /a/b' ) where id = 1 

select doc from #t
```

But if you have the doc copied to a variable, you'll have to update it like this:

```
create table #t( id int, doc xml)
insert into #t(id,doc) values (1,'<a><b/></a>')

declare @doc xml = ( select doc from #t where id =1 )

set @doc.modify( 'delete /a/b' )     

update #t set doc = @doc where id = 1

select doc from #t
```

Comment: I am trying to reinsert my column with an update statement but its giving me this error  Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
The data types text and varchar(max) are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: using this command -->          update [dbo].[tbl_reports] 
      set info = cast(@xml as varchar(max)) 
      where info = cast(@oldXML as varchar(max))

Comment: That's probably because the column info is of type 'text', and "The data types text and varchar(max) are incompatible in the equal to operator".  Why are you using the old 'text' datatype?

Comment: Its been set up this way since the beginning

Comment: Is there any type of casting i can do to resave it ?

Comment: You should identify the row to update using its key, not some text value.

Comment: Ok so i will need to use a second cursor aka my pkey since my first cursor is on that text node because i am looping through it and editing values

Comment: "Ok so i will need to use a second cursor" almost certainly not.  But I have no idea what your code is doing.

Comment: @abarz12, what you are doing is dangerous... You cannot compare an XML with another. Yes, you can compare their string representation, but there are certain differences, which are equal, but not the same (e.g. `<a></a>` vs. `<a/>` and whitespaces...) **And be aware, that you should use `NVARCHAR` at least**. And try to use the native XML type as soon as possible. Storing XML as `NVARCHAR` is bad, `VARCHAR` is worse, using `NTEXT` is ugly, `TEXT` is horrible... `IMAGE` is the most worst ugliest :-D